# XElement 'Add' Not doing it right?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Using:

```
XElement kd = XElement.Load(path);
kd.Add(new XElement("players",
       new XAttribute("name", username),
       new XElement("kills", 0),
       new XElement("deaths", 0)));
```

Nothing is added to XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SimpleKD>
  <player name="Tardis">
    <kills>0</kills>
    <deaths>0</deaths>
    </player>
</SimpleKD>
```

Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not appear to be saving the file. Try

```
kd.Save(path);
```

Comment: God, I feel like an idiot. I searched forever, and didnt even realise.